# Synchronizing on a static object

Tags: java, static, synchronization

I am really confused on how synchronization actually work. I have this following code:

```
public class FunTest {
    static FunTest test;

    public void method() {
        synchronized (test) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().getName() == "Random1") {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test = new FunTest();
        final FunTest t0 = new FunTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                t0.method();
            }
        });
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                t0.method();
            }
        });
        t1.setName("Random1");
        t3.setName("Random2");
        t1.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

The code throws `IllegalMonitorStateException` when run. I don't understand why this is happening. Is it not possible to acquire lock this way?

If I replace `test` with `this` in synchronization block it works fine though. Why is this so?

Comment: I added the most important tag; the language. Please verify.

Comment: And you might want to make `test` `final` so it can't be reassigned.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening a monitor block on `test`, but your applying `wait()` and `notify()` to `this`.

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc of wait()

> "The current thread must own this object's monitor"

In your case it is not.

changing  `t0.method();` to `test.method()` will work. Not sure about your usecase though.

Comment: *changing `t0.method()` to `test.method()` will work* -- indeed, but IMO this is a dangerous workaround. It actually makes `this` and `test` the same thing in `method()`'s body, in this very particular case, but that might confuse the OP. @MauricePerry's explanation is clearer for the OP in my opinion. (I'm not downvoting though, because it's a valid answer)